# How do I get the variable value outside of EventListener function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have this code where I want to access the variable value outside the `EventListener` function to capture which button was clicked so that I can show a modal window with the relevant button value. Please help.

Here, in the code below, I want to assign value to the variable `wordClicked`.

```
const btn1OpenModal = document.querySelector(".word-one");

const btn2OpenModal = document.querySelector(".word-two");

const btn3OpenModal = document.querySelector(".word-three");

const btn4OpenModal = document.querySelector(".word-four");

export let wordClicked;

btn1OpenModal.addEventListener("click", function () {
  openModal();
  wordClicked = "firstWord";
});

btn2OpenModal.addEventListener("click", function () {
  openModal();
  wordClicked = "secondWord";
});

btn3OpenModal.addEventListener("click", function () {
  openModal();
  wordClicked = "thirdWord";
});

btn4OpenModal.addEventListener("click", function () {
  openModal();
  wordClicked = "fourthWord";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't export a variable, only a value.

**At the time** you `export` the value of `wordClicked`, that value is `undefined`.

You can't change the exported value later.

---

You could export an *object* and then later change a property of that object, but likely you will need to make the event listener functions themselves responsible for opening the model.

Comment: any suggestions on how to get the value out of the variable?

For example, here if btn1 is clicked, then value of wordClicked should be 'firstWord'.

I can then use this value in another js script. Is that possible by some code?

Comment: @riteshgaggar — As the first three paragraphs of this answer say: No.

Comment: ok, thanks. Will try to modify the code in some other way.